# Show hidden option using argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I'm using argprase to create an option, and it's a very specific option to do one specific job. The script currently has roughly 30 knobs, and most aren't used regularly.

I'm creating an option:

```
opt.add_argument('-opt',help="Some Help", help=argparse.SUPPRESS)
```

But i want there to be two ways to show the help for the script:

```
my_script -help
my_script -help-long
```

I want the -help-long to also show all the hidden args. I couldn't find a way to do this.

Is there a way to implement this behavior?

Comment: I don't think that's possible, since you're overwriting the attribute help with `argparse.SUPPRESS` which is actually a string: `'==SUPPRESS=='`.
Whn you look into the implementation of `add_argument` you can see that the entire method is skipped if `help=='==SUPPRESS=='`

Comment: Sorry this is off topic - I was wondering what knobs means in this context - I Googled for computer code knobs and did not see anything relevant.

Comment: It's just a synonym for option.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't think there's a builtin way to support this.  You can probably hack around it by checking `sys.argv` directly and using that to modify how you build the parser:

```
import sys
show_hidden_args = '--help-long' in sys.argv

opt = argparse.ArgumentParser()
opt.add_argument('--hidden-arg', help='...' if show_hidden_args else argparse.SUPPRESS)
opt.add_argument('--help-long', help='Show all options.', action='help')


args = opt.parse_args()
```

Of course, if writing this over and over is too inconvenient, you can wrap it in a helper function (or subclass `ArgumentParser`):

```
def add_hidden_argument(*args, **kwargs):
    if not show_hidden_args:
        kwargs['help'] = argparse.SUPPRESS
    opt.add_argument(*args, **kwargs)
```

And you'll probably want to add a non-hidden `--help-long` argument so that users know what it supposedly does...

Comment: This works and seems to be the cleanest solution not using undocumented features

Answer (score 2):

This is a variation on @mgilson's answer, looking in `sys.argv` to see whether we should suppress some help or not

```
import argparse
import sys

def hide_args(arglist):
    for action in arglist:
        action.help=argparse.SUPPRESS

hidelist=[]     
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
a1 = parser.add_argument('--foo',help='normal')
a2 = parser.add_argument('--bar',help='hidden')
hidelist.append(a2)

if '-h' in sys.argv[1:]:
    hide_args(hidelist)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Here I've chosen to interpret `--help` as asking for a long help; `-h` for the short.  I could have added a separate `--longhelp` argument instead.

```
1207:~/mypy$ python3 stack37303960.py --help
usage: stack37303960.py [-h] [--foo FOO] [--bar BAR]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  --foo FOO   normal
  --bar BAR   hidden
```

for a short help

```
1207:~/mypy$ python3 stack37303960.py -h
usage: stack37303960.py [-h] [--foo FOO]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  --foo FOO   normal
```

`add_argument` returns a pointer to the `Action` object that it created. Here I save selected ones in the `hidelist`.  Then I conditionally iterate through that list and change the `help` to `SUPPRESS`.  Many of the attributes of an Action can be changed after the initial creation (experiment in an interactive session).

The parser also maintains a list of actions.  The default `help` is the first one on the `parser._actions` list.  It uses this list both for parsing and formatting the help.

```
In [540]: parser._actions[0]
Out[540]: _HelpAction(option_strings=['-h', '--help'], dest='help', nargs=0, const=None, default='==SUPPRESS==', type=None, choices=None, help='show this help message and exit', metavar=None)
```

Comment: FWIW, you're proposing reliance on a bunch of undocumented argparse features.  That last time I checked, it wasn't documented that `parser.add_argument` returns _anything_.  With that said, the argparse internals _seem_ to be fairly stable, so the risk you're taking on probably isn't _too_ big.

Comment: `argparse` documentation is a little weak in that sort of thing.  It has a lot of how-to detail, but does not systematically describe the classes and how they are generated.   Since I do most of my `argparse` testing in an Ipython session, it's become second nature.  In http://bugs.python.org/issue19462 I suggest some similar actions for a poster who wanted a `remove_argument` method.

Comment: I mentioned 2 years ago in a bug/issue that the return of `add_argument` is not documented.  http://bugs.python.org/msg225794.  But there are more useful fixes in the queue.

Comment: I was looking into your solution, and it seemed to be the quickest, however i don't like using undocumented features. I was shortening the code a bit by using: `hidelist.append (parser.add_argument(...))`

Comment: I can't imagine debugging a custom Action class (as documented) without being able to access the object created by `add_argument`.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve something by subclassing `ArgumentParser` and `_HelpAction`:

```
class LongHelp(argparse._HelpAction):
    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __call__(cls, parser, namespace, values, option_string):
        print(parser.long_help)

class ArgParserWithLongHelp(argparse.ArgumentParser):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(self)
        self.long_help = {}
        self.add_argument("--long-help", action=LongHelp )

    def add_argument(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if kwargs.get('long_help'):
            self.long_help.update({k:kwargs['long_help'] for k in args})
            kwargs.pop('long_help')
        super().add_argument(*args, **kwargs)

opt =  ArgParserWithLongHelp()
opt.add_argument('-opt', help=argparse.SUPPRESS, long_help='Some extra help')
args = opt.parse_args()
```

Comment: This doesn't format the help message at all like argparse normally does so it would make using this a little odd -- Or you need to store the data in a more structured format and do a good bit more work to format the help message in a more useful manner (which I don't think is a trivial task).

Comment: Yes it was just to show the idea. Maybe _HelpAction formatting method could be used. Your solution is certainly more straight forward.

Comment: This works better if you add an additional property to the argument: `hidden`.  If invoked with `--help`, then `_HelpAction` disregards anything that's `hidden`.  `--help-long` invokes both.  You could even make `--help-long` hidden, if necessary.

Comment: @DougR.: I like the idea. How would add a `hidden` property to the argument though ?

Comment: @JacquesGaudin--I don't know the internals of `argparse` very well.  But subclass `argparse` and override `argparse.add_argument()`.  Add an optional parameter `hidden=False` which sets a property on the argument object (it appears from the code & docs as if args are stored as objects) and then passes the remaining to `super().add_argument()`.  Do something similar for `_HelpAction` that swaps the help message for `argparse.SUPPRESS` (and back), then passes to `super()...` when called.  I don't have time to do the research & generate code, or I would write this up myself.